# Never change state within an expression

Tags: c, function, function-call

First I want share with you [this](https://github.com/mcinglis/c-style#never-change-state-within-an-expression-eg-with-assignments-or-) repository on Github, where it is mentioned some good practices to current time of programming in C. Here it is mentioned that:

> Never change state in an expression [...]

In this regard, I would like to know what's the difference between.

```
trie_add( *child, ++word );     // Bad
```

and

```
trie_add( *child, word + 1 );   // Good
```

Can someone explain this in more detail?

Comment: The first changes the value of `word` as a side effect. Whether this is *good* or *bad* is opinion-based.

Comment: Print the value of `word` after both statements and you'll see the difference.

Comment: So the [compact implementation of `strcpy`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/string.h/strcpy#Usage_and_implementation) is bad? :-P

Comment: I disagree with many of the points in the article, please don't take it as a sacred truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a genral view, in case you use

```
 trie_add( *child, ++word );
```

the `word` is having a side-effect in form of a pre-increment. In many cases, using this approach causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of the lack of a [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

However, the call

```
trie_add( *child, word + 1 );
```

does not have a side-effect on `word`.

FWIW, both the calls pass the same *value* to the called function.

That said, just to clear things up, the quoted statement is just another opinion and not any *rule*. In *this* particular example, both are fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I understand

Comment: I don't see the need for a sequence point in the expression, as I don't see the need in `foo(a++, b++, c++, d++);`

Comment: @pmg right sir, not here, but if the first _approach_ is used for more than once on a single variable, then it will cause an issue. Second approach (like `+1`, `+2`) will be safe, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Never change state in an expression

This is far too strict. As it was mentioned, there's nothing really bad in `trie_add( *child, ++word );`.

But one have to be cautious, as in `trie_add2( *child, ++word, ++word );` the evaluation order is not fixed, so the compiler is free to produce the equivalent of either `trie_add2( *child, word+1, word+2);` or `trie_add2( *child, word+2, word+1);`